# get selected object in colum header viewgrid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I've this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var input 
    $("#<%=GridViewBin.ClientID%> tr th a").hover(function() {          
        $("#<%=GridViewBin.ClientID%> tr th input").each(function (index) {
            //HERE I HAVE TO get selected object, HOW?
            input = $(this);
        })
        $(input).show();            
   },function() {
        $(input).hide(); 

   });
});
```

I want to get ID about input selected to show or hide. This input it is in column header in gridview.

Any clue or help?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var input; 
        $("#<%=GridViewBin.ClientID%> tr th a").hover(function() {          
            $("#<%=GridViewBin.ClientID%> tr th input").each(function (index) {
                //get selected object
                input = $(this);
            })
            $(input).show();            
       },function() {
            $(input).hide(); 

       });
    });
```

Missing **';'** after var declaration.